What is the function of よ at the end of an interrogative?
From what I know, questions in Japanese typically end with か or ね. However, there are occasions where I find a question that ends with よ instead. Am I supposed to interpret this as the speaker saying the scentence in the tone of a question, or does よ have a function in this case that I am not aware of?

My immediate thought is 「なんだよ」, where the なん clarifies that it is a question, and the よ would indicate maybe an angry tone; I note that よ does not invite agreement by the listener, unlike か or ね. However, I do not recall a moment where it had grammatical merit outside of colloquialisms.

A question mark is sometimes used with a declarative sentence ending in よ, to (I believe) indicate a rising tone. For example, 「いえいえ、そんなことはありませんよ？」

Your best bet would be to provide an example...
